How to search and replace bash variable with braces?
I have the following:
var='before {{BODY_PARAM}} after'
body_arg='body'

Using ${var/{{BODY_PARAM}}/${body_arg} emits before }} after}/body.
How do I use bash variable search and replace syntax to replace {{BODY_PARAM}} with body?

Are you by any chance reading a file line by line in a shell loop, populating var for each line and trying to do transformations like the one in your question on each line? If so, there are much better ways, see why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice.

@CharlesDuffy, judging from the result, it looks to me as if bash isn't nesting the braces as I would like and instead interpreting the first close brace as the end of entire ${}

@EdMorton, what I'm doing is implementing the decorator pattern. When I posted this question, I had wanted to use Gherkin syntax but once I started down that path, I realized it would really mess up syntax highlighting and formatting (so I've stuck with using guillemets instead of braces).

@NoelYep, indeed, the inner {s are just data rather than syntax so the parser doesn't pay them any particular attention.

@CharlesDuffy, sorry, I had misread your post and upon rereading it, now see that you were responding to someone else.

@NoelYap There might be something in what you said that means something I'm not picking up on but best I can tell that's irrelevant to my question -  no matter if you're implementing the decorator [patter or whatever you use for wrapping your target strings, I was just asking if you're reading the input line by line from a file or not because if you are there are better approaches.

For example, you might want to use ${BODY_PARAM} instead of {{BODY_PARAM}} in your input (or do sed 's/{\({[[:alnum:]_]+}\)}/$\1/g' or similar to convert the latter into the former) and then use envsubst to convert all of your placeholders at once (assuming you have or can create associated environment variables). We just can't tell what the best approach would be for you without more implementation context in the form of a [mcve].

@EdMorton, no, I'm not reading from a file.

The easiest solution is just to quote:
$ var='before {{BODY_PARAM}} after'
$ body_arg='body'
$ echo "${var/'{{BODY_PARAM}}'/$body_arg}"
before body after

If for some reason you're attached to the curly-braces in the replacement section, more quoting lets you keep those too:
$ echo "${var/'{{BODY_PARAM}}'/"${body_arg}"}"
before body after

(All transcripts above from bash 5.2.15).

In bash versions before 4.3, the second one will include literal double-quotes in the output.

One way to do it is to use a variable for {{BODY_PARAM}}:
var='before {{BODY_PARAM}} after'
body_arg='body'

body_param='{{BODY_PARAM}}'
echo "${var/${body_param}/${body_arg}}"


I don't see why this deserves a downvote -- it's not wrong in any way, and the practice is one I sometimes follow.
